# Why does HTMLAgilityPack remove my closing tag?

Tags: c#, .net, tags, html-agility-pack

Using htmlagilitypack in .NET (C#) and have some html code as such:

```
<p><ol><li>A bunch of text</li></ol><em>some em text</em> more text here.</p>
```

I then load it into a doc and save it via LoadHtml and Save functions. But I end up with:

```
<p><ol><li>A bunch of text</li></ol><em>some em text</em> more text here.
```

The last closing p tag is gone.

Why is this happening? How to fix it?

Comment: Having an <ol> inside a <p> is not valid HTML, so that might be what is causing the problem.

Comment: is there a way to allow it anyway?

Comment: Why do you want to produce invalid HTML?

Comment: can you just tell me yes or no

Comment: Why not just stop doing it in the first place? It's invalid HTML and bad things might happen.

Comment: Maybe try reading up on the documentation yourself if you don't want to have a dialogue about your problems?

Comment: maybe I did read and didn't find an answer and that's why I'm here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others said in the comments, it's an invalid HTML so that might be the reason why the `HtmlDocument` class itself is removing `</p>` in the end when you store it into a file using the `Save` method, but as a workaround, you can store it using `System.IO.File` class and store the `document.Text` at the output location.

```
var html = "<p><ol><li>A bunch of text</li></ol><em>some em text</em> more text here.</p>";
var document = new HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(html);
File.WriteAllText("insert_your_path_here", document.Text);
```

Comment: @E.D. because they're trying to force you fix HTML and I gave you a dirty quick workaround :)